# How to build dynamic cfarguments in ColdFusion9?

Tags: coldfusion, arguments, coldfusion-9, cfloop

I have simple form that has more than 100 fields. All these fields are submitted to `cffunction` where I have SQL code that will run Insert or Update query. Here is example of my code:

```
    var formData = $('#'+frmID).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Components/MyFunction.cfc?method=userRecord',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(obj){
        if(obj.STATUS === 200){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    });
```

Here is cffunction:

```
<cffunction name="userRecord" access="remote" output="true" returnformat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="userID" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="userFName" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="userLName" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="userDOB" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="userGender" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="userAddress" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="userCity" type="string" required="true">
    .... And there is more field in this form


    <cfset fnResults = StructNew()>
    //Here is SQL query for insert and update
    <cfreturn fnResults>
</cffunction>
```

Instead of creating all arguments manually is there a way to use cfloop and collect all the arguments dynamically? I couldn't find any article or example. Would that be a good option or creating arguments manually is better approach? If anyone can help please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: in this case can't you pass all the fields in a single structure?

Comment: @Vineesh How that will change what I already have?

Comment: @espresso_coffee pass the entire form struct in to the function, so there's only one argument being accepted which is a struct of all the form fields.

Comment: @MattBusche Can you please provide  example ?

Comment: This would be incredibly simple without the javascript.  Are you sure it's actually necessary?

Comment: @DanBracuk which part you are wondering if it's necessary?

Comment: The use of javascript to submit the form.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes I have to use Javascript. Is there a way to get argument name while looping through arguments in cffunction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the data as a structure.

```
<cffunction name="userRecord" access="remote" output="true" returnformat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="formData" type="structure" required="true">

    <cfloop collection="#arguments.formData#" item="key">
        #key#: #arguments.formData[key]#
    </cfloop>

    <cfset fnResults = StructNew()>
    //Here is SQL query for insert and update
    <cfreturn fnResults>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I want to build arguments with cfloop. I have over 100 arguments in my form and I don't want to hard code each of them.

Comment: You can use `<cfloop collection="#arguments.formData#" item="key">
        #key#: #myStructure[key]#
   </cfloop>` Updated in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the entire form data as a structure.

```
var formData = $('#'+frmID).serializeArray();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Components/MyFunction.cfc?method=userRecord',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(obj){
    if(obj.STATUS === 200){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(errorThrown);
});

<cffunction name="userRecord" access="remote" output="true" returnformat="JSON">
  <cfargument name="form" type="struct" required="true">
  <cfdump var="#arguments.form#">

</cffunction>
```

Comment: How to get the name of the cfaruments?

Comment: Dump out the arguments, like I did in the answer?

Comment: Can I use cfloop and get the name for each argument?